# Update Text in SelectedItem in Combobox

Tags: c#, sql

How to update selecteditem in combobox when we edit in selecteditem.
this is my coding :

```
SqlConnection CON2 = new SqlConnection();
                    CON2.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TWPLSOFTWARE;Integrated Security=True";
                    CON2.Open();
                    SqlCommand CMD1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ITEM_GROUP SET ITEM_GROUP_NAME=@IGN WHERE ITEM_GROUP_NAME=@IGN", CON2);
                    CMD1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IGN", comboBox2.Text.ToString()));
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    CMD1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Am I missing something in this coding?

Comment: Do you have an exception or error message? Did you tried your query in SQL Server? And more important, please read [faq] and [ask] before asking a question. You don't have to write all title with UPPERCASE.

Comment: _"Am I missing something"_ - yes, you did not mention what this should do, what it does (give an error, for example?) and what you have tried to solve that difference.

Comment: @CodeCaster Mission completed.

Comment: Not the problem, but no need to do comboBox2.Text.ToString(). The text-property already is a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your query doesn't update anything.

Say you have an entry called "Foo" and you want to update it to "Bar", your query now looks like:

```
UPDATE ITEM_GROUP SET ITEM_GROUP_NAME='Bar' WHERE ITEM_GROUP_NAME='Bar'
```

You'll have to specify the existing name (or preferably the ID), not the new one in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain what is your query exactly do, **nothing**;

```
"UPDATE ITEM_GROUP SET ITEM_GROUP_NAME=@IGN WHERE ITEM_GROUP_NAME=@IGN"
```

You tried to update all `ITEM_GROUP_NAME` to `@IGN`, where `ITEM_GROUP_NAME`'s are `@IGN`, which means you tried to update all `ITEM_GROUP_NAME`'s values to itself (Which values are `@IGN`).

Please check out these articles more carefuly;

- [`SQL UPDATE Statement`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)
- [`Update (SQL) from Wikipedia`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29)

Comment: i want to update ITEM_GROUP_NAME FROM ITEM_GROUP_NAME BY TEXT IN COMBOBOX. So what can i do?